# My jquery is not working in my to do list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make a to do list using jquery but its not working Please someone tell me whats wrong with my code.My input is working fine but my sortable function,draggable and droppable function is not working .Here is my code..

```js
$(function() {
    
   $('#todoList ul').sortable({
       items: "li:not('.listTitle, .addItem')",
       connectWith: "ul",
       dropOnEmpty: true,
       placeholder: "emptySpace"
       
   });
    
    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
           var item = $(this).val();
           
           $(this).parent().parent().append('<li>' + item + '</li>' ); 
           $(this).val('');
       } 
    });
    
    $('#trash').droppable({
       drop:function(event, ui) {
           ui.draggable.remove();
       } 
    });
});
```

```css
/* Styles */

body{
    background: #eee;
    margin: 100px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}


#todoListWrapper {
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
}

#todoList:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}

ul {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1%;
    list-style: none;
}


ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    border-color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:active{
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}

#todoList ul {
    width: 14.28%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#todoList li{
    background: none; 
    padding: 5px;
    border: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#todoList li:hover{
    background: #eee;
}

#todoList li.listTitle {
    background: #444;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: solid 1px white;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#todoList li.listTitle:hover,
#todoList li.listTitle:active{
    cursor: default;
    transform: none;
}

#todoList .emptySpace{
    background: #fc3;
    border: dashed 1px #777;
    height: 10px;
}

#todoList li.addItem {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: none;
}

#todoList ul:hover li.addItem {
    display: block;
}

#todoList li.addItem input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
}

#todoList li.addItem:active {
    transform: none;
}

#trash {
    background: rgba(178,73,38,.7);
    margin:80px 280px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
    <head>
        
        <title>JQuery To-do List</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalise.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="dostyle.css">
        
        <link href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    
    </head>
     
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container" id="todoListWrapper">
            <h2>JQuery TO-DO List</h2>
           <div id="todoList">
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Monday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Tuesday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Wednesday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Thrusday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Friday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Saturday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                   <li class="listTitle">Sunday</li>
                   <li class="addItem"><input type="text" placeholder="add new item.."></li>
               </ul>
               
            </div>
            
            <div id="trash" class="container">Drag items to delete</div>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- Load CDN -->
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Load local if CDN not available -->
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"><\/script>');</script> 
        
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> 
        
    </body> 
    
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes here: `li:not('.listTitle, .addItem')`

Answer (score 0):

There is a error in your code. The wrapped function will never execute, it is an anonymous function and you are not calling it immediately. Change the script as below, change it to IIFE. I have invoked the function by adding () at the end.

```
$(function() {

   $('#todoList ul').sortable({
       items: "li:not('.listTitle, .addItem')",
       connectWith: "ul",
       dropOnEmpty: true,
       placeholder: "emptySpace"

   });

    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
           var item = $(this).val();

           $(this).parent().parent().append('<li>' + item + '</li>' ); 
           $(this).val('');
       } 
    });

    $('#trash').droppable({
       drop:function(event, ui) {
           ui.draggable.remove();
       } 
    });
})();
```